# Find certain words and replace them

Tags: javascript, replace, innerhtml, getelementbyid, words

I'd like to find:

"**New York**" and replace it with "**New York City**"
"**Washington**" and replace it with "**Seattle**"
"**Florida**" and replace it with "**Jacksonville**"
"**South-Carolina**" and replace it with "**Columbia**"
"**West_Virginia**" and replace it with "**Charleston**"

I made the following example code below, but that doesn't seem to work:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N3ZmS/

```
<td id="dont-replace-them">
New York<br />
Washington<br />
Florida<br />
South-Carolina<br />
West_Virginia<br />
</td>

<br />

<td id="replace-them">
New York<br />
Washington<br />
Florida<br />
South-Carolina<br />
West_Virginia<br />
</td>

<script type="text/javascript">
function replaceWords() {
    document.getElementById("replace-them").innerHTML.replace("New York", "New York City");
    document.getElementById("replace-them").innerHTML.replace("Washington", "Seattle");
    document.getElementById("replace-them").innerHTML.replace("Florida", "Jacksonville");
    document.getElementById("replace-them").innerHTML.replace("South-Carolina", "Columbia");
    document.getElementById("replace-them").innerHTML.replace("West_Virginia", "Charleston");
};  
</script>
```

Anyone know what should be fixed to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.replace();` returns the replaced string, it doesn't alter the string in the DOM.

```
var str = 'foobar';
str.replace('foobar', 'lorem ipsum');    // Returns 'lorem ipsum', but does no DOM manipulation.
```

You'll need to save the results of each `.replace()` into a temporary variable, and then update the DOM afterwards.

```
function replaceWords(el) {
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML
                    .replace('New York', 'New York City')
                    .replace('Washington', 'Seattle')
                    .replace('Florida', 'Jacksonville')
                    .replace('South-Carolina', 'Columbia')
                    .replace('West_Virginia', 'Charleston');
}

replaceWords(document.getElementById('replace-them'));
```

Comment: That's because your `td` is orphaned in the middle of the DOM. I replaced it with a `p`, and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/N3ZmS/3/

Comment: Yes... just structure the `td` properly: http://jsfiddle.net/N3ZmS/4/ . If your `td` is orphaned in the DOM, then you need to fix that underlying issue first.

Comment: I didn't know the structure mattered for the example, but in this case it does! ;) Thanks for all your help Julian!

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply the new string value to the DOM element

```
document.getElementById("replace-them").innerHTML =
    document.getElementById("replace-them").innerHTML.replace("New York", "New York City");
// etc.
```

Incidentally, after defining the function `replaceWords()` you also need to make sure you actually call it.

You also need to use a `div` or similar element for the markup to render correctly.

Working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/N3ZmS/1/).